# What questions should we migrate to Gardening

Tags: discussion

Per [this meta.so post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152597/how-to-migrate-old-questions-to-a-new-graduated-site), if we want to migrate old questions to gardening now, we need to build a list and coordinate with the Gardening site to get some agreement on a mass-migration. If you're wondering why, [we can't migrate questions older than 60 days anymore](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151890/disable-migration-for-questions-older-than-60-days).

Important notes:

- We cannot give SE a list of tags, they must be a list of individual posts.
- This is a one-time request, so we need to be sure everything is included in our list.

Comment: Related (but predating the "no migrations for old questions" rule): http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/questions/347/questions-that-should-be-migrated-to-gardening-and-landscaping

Comment: @NiallC. Agreed, it's come up several times before. The old plan was to migrate only if needed. But now our choice is to close them as off topic when they show activity or have SE do a preemptive mass migration. I think there are too many good questions out there that shouldn't need to be closed.

Comment: This one:
http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/6464/how-to-clear-an-overgrown-flower-bed-and-prep-for-grass

Comment: Honestly, @Steven is right -- but the entire `lawn` and `grass` tag needs investigation.

Comment: @Aarthi Agreed, unless someone beats me to it, I'll start digging through a bunch of those tags next week.

Answer (score 1):

A few things we should do:

- Clean up any dups on DIY.
- Check for dups on Gardening.
- Decide if drainage, french drains, and other runoff questions belong on DIY or Gardening.
- Decide if ponds belong on DIY or Gardening.

I've reviewed the following tags:
[chainsaw](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chainsaw) [compost](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compost) [drainage](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drainage) [excavator](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/excavator) [french-drain](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/french-drain) [gardening](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gardening) [grass](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grass) [gravel](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gravel) [irrigation](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/irrigation) [landscaping](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/landscaping) [lawn](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lawn) [lawn-mower](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lawn-mower) [moss](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moss) [outdoor](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/outdoor) [patio](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/patio) [pavers](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pavers) [planting](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planting) [pond](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pond) [rain](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rain) [turf](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/turf)

Here are the questions I think are potential migration targets:

[Does liquid aerification work?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/56/does-liquid-aerification-work)

[What technique should I use to remove rubble from earth, using a small excavator?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/489/what-technique-should-i-use-to-remove-rubble-from-earth-using-a-small-excavator) (borderline)

[What is the best kind of grass/seed for a completely shaded lawn?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/1035/what-is-the-best-kind-of-grass-seed-for-a-completely-shaded-lawn)

[Bermuda grass is invading my Kentucky Blue? Any solutions that don't involve Roundup?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/1047/bermuda-grass-is-invading-my-kentucky-blue-any-solutions-that-dont-involve-rou)

[Is it safe to spray herbicide on the bark of a tree if you don't get it on the leaves?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/1067/is-it-safe-to-spray-herbicide-on-the-bark-of-a-tree-if-you-dont-get-it-on-the-l)

[What are the steps for landscaping a lawn?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/what-are-the-steps-for-landscaping-a-lawn)

[What are some recommended cordless trimmers/weed-eaters?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/1235/what-are-some-recommended-cordless-trimmers-weed-eaters) (borderline, product recommendation, VTC?)

[What is a cheap patio solution for a muddy area in my backyard?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/1681/what-is-a-cheap-patio-solution-for-a-muddy-area-in-my-backyard)

[Small amounts of moss on asphalt shingles?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/1729/small-amounts-of-moss-on-asphalt-shingles) (borderline)

[Can plants be planted over a drain field?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/1855/can-plants-be-planted-over-a-drain-field) (borderline)

[How do I care for the land area directly above a septic tank?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/2023/how-do-i-care-for-the-land-area-directly-above-a-septic-tank)

[Drought-Resistant Lawn/Turf Recommendation For Area Above Septic](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/2129/drought-resistant-lawn-turf-recommendation-for-area-above-septic)

[Are there other advantages to using turf over grass seed besides getting instant results?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/2282/are-there-other-advantages-to-using-turf-over-grass-seed-besides-getting-instant)

[Is there a quick way to clean up walnuts from a yard?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/2320/is-there-a-quick-way-to-clean-up-walnuts-from-a-yard)

[How do I build a French drain?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/2865/how-do-i-build-a-french-drain) (borderline)

[How should I drain fuel from my mower?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/2947/how-should-i-drain-fuel-from-my-mower)

[How do I remove moss from an outdoor brick walkway?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/3465/how-do-i-remove-moss-from-an-outdoor-brick-walkway)

[Extending a pebble path for an old home](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/3786/extending-a-pebble-path-for-an-old-home) (borderline)

[How do you best help trees that have been damaged by severe freezing?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/4731/how-do-you-best-help-trees-that-have-been-damaged-by-severe-freezing)

[How to promote garden drainage?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/4841/how-to-promote-garden-drainage) (borderline)

[How do I fix a sinkhole in my backyard?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/4889/how-do-i-fix-a-sinkhole-in-my-backyard) (borderline)

[How to get rid of a burned coal smell that's coming to my flat?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/4977/how-to-get-rid-of-a-burned-coal-smell-thats-coming-to-my-flat)

[French Drain with rubber mulch?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/5000/french-drain-with-rubber-mulch) (borderline)

[What are good cleaners to use on pruning shears?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/5198/what-are-good-cleaners-to-use-on-pruning-shears) (borderline)

[How do I stop weeds in desert landscaping?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/5213/how-do-i-stop-weeds-in-desert-landscaping)

[How to ensure proper drainage in a back yard](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/5226/how-to-ensure-proper-drainage-in-a-back-yard) (borderline)

[How do I level a small yard?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/5227/how-do-i-level-a-small-yard)

[Non-toxic materials for edging garden](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/5254/non-toxic-materials-for-edging-garden)

[What can I do about my lawn growing unevenly/patchy?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/5278/what-can-i-do-about-my-lawn-growing-unevenly-patchy)

[Online landscape design](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/online-landscape-design)

[Storing riding lawnmower under deck](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/5361/storing-riding-lawnmower-under-deck) (borderline)

[Ground cover needed](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/5387/ground-cover-needed)

[Mowing a badly inclining lawn](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/5492/mowing-a-badly-inclining-lawn)

[What material should a year-round green house in high elevation be made of?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/5512/what-material-should-a-year-round-green-house-in-high-elevation-be-made-of) (borderline)

[Can I use packing popcorn (peanuts) instead of gravel for filling a french drain?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/5771/can-i-use-packing-popcorn-peanuts-instead-of-gravel-for-filling-a-french-drain) (borderline)

[Building a raised wall for a pond](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/5801/building-a-raised-wall-for-a-pond) (likely belongs on DIY)

[White solid drain pipe vs black flexible corrugated pipe for a french drain](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/5803/white-solid-drain-pipe-vs-black-flexible-corrugated-pipe-for-a-french-drain) (borderline)

[Natural/Free Composting Liner](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/5866/natural-free-composting-liner)

[Replacing pavers with grass, what do I do with the sand?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/6076/replacing-pavers-with-grass-what-do-i-do-with-the-sand)

[Building a Pond](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/6257/building-a-pond) (borderline)

[How to clear an overgrown flower bed and prep for grass](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/6464/how-to-clear-an-overgrown-flower-bed-and-prep-for-grass)

[How do I stop backyard from flooding when it rains hard?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/how-do-i-stop-backyard-from-flooding-when-it-rains-hard)

[Why is my tall fescue wilting?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/6544/why-is-my-tall-fescue-wilting)

[Mixed Shade/Light Grass issues](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/6586/mixed-shade-light-grass-issues)

[I over-fertilized my lawn. Now what do I do?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/6873/i-over-fertilized-my-lawn-now-what-do-i-do)

[Is it possible to a drill hole in the bottom of a terracotta gardening pot?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/6940/is-it-possible-to-a-drill-hole-in-the-bottom-of-a-terracotta-gardening-pot)

[How often should I change the oil in my lawn mower](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/7076/how-often-should-i-change-the-oil-in-my-lawn-mower)

[How to sharpen a lawn mower blade?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/7304/how-to-sharpen-a-lawn-mower-blade) (dup exists on gardening: https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/2325/what-is-the-best-way-to-sharpen-a-lawn-mower-blade)

[How do I handle a transition from concrete to dirt underneath a flagstone patio?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/7999/how-do-i-handle-a-transition-from-concrete-to-dirt-underneath-a-flagstone-patio) (borderline)

[Would building a partial raised wall for a pond in this way be strong enough?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/8328/would-building-a-partial-raised-wall-for-a-pond-in-this-way-be-strong-enough) (likely belongs on DIY, possible dup of 5801)

[Rain/irrigation run-off drain pipe opening constant dripping](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/14092/rain-irrigation-run-off-drain-pipe-opening-constant-dripping) (borderline)

[Does concrete sealant slow the growth of moss?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/12575/does-concrete-sealant-slow-the-growth-of-moss) (borderline)

[Drilling "misting" pin holes in PVC](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/15208/drilling-misting-pin-holes-in-pvc) (borderline)

[How to remove moss from my roof?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/16364/how-to-remove-moss-from-my-roof) (dup of 1729)

[Should a curtain drain be covered/back filled?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/18813/should-a-curtain-drain-be-covered-back-filled) (borderline)

[How to address mold/moss on newer roof?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/20113/how-to-address-mold-moss-on-newer-roof) (dup of 1729)