# Should we migrate on-topic questions that are better suited to Woodworking?

Tags: discussion, migration

This [recent question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/69743/dust-after-staining-and-poly-advice) about finishing a table top would likely get more and higher quality answers over at the new Woodworking Beta site. What's the procedure for migrating a question that's still on-topic here, but fits in better on another site? Should I just flag it and write an explanation?

I found a few [questions](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/726/what-questions-should-we-migrate-to-gardening) on Meta similar to this for Gardening & Landscaping migration, but it seemed to deal more with specific topics rather than general practices.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general - No.

If a question is on topic here it should remain here. Questions should really only be migrated if they are a) good and b) off topic. The fact that we have an overlap with Woodworking shouldn't really come into it.

However, if the OP requests that a question is migrated, *then* I'm very likely to honour that request.

In this specific instance, I'd probably migrate (but I'd like to see some more input from other users first).

Answer (score 0):

Might there be a way to keep the question but post a flag to the other site that would let them cross reference in their search engine? That way, the Q&A would only need to appear on one of the sister sites but would be accessible to both when searching.

Needs a coding change that may have its own problems, but a thought.

Answer (score 0):

No,

When as a DIYer I ask how to  finish a table, I am looking for a easy way that gives a reasonable result that does not require me to first build myself a workshop or buy lots of equipment.

I think woodworking is about getting the best possible result regardless.

Comment: While I think the correct answer here is probably "no" for reasons @ChrisF states, I'd like to clarify that Woodworking is open to questions from beginners too, and you seem to be assuming otherwise. There isn't a requirement that every user be a seasoned woodworker with a full shop of tools. Most of the users over at Woodworking are good about taking into account an OP's requests for "hand tools only" or "using X and Y tools only."

Comment: @Doresoom, but I expect it is assume that quality of the "woodworking" is as important if not more then solving a problem where the solution happens to use wood.

Comment: With that assumption that DIY is solely here for a "git 'er done" attitude, then the OP for the DIY question this whole post was centered around would have just dumped a can of poly on the table and been done with the whole thing.