# I posted here, but it seems like a better fit for Woodworking Beta

Tags: support, migration

I hadn't noticed the existence of Woodworking (which may not have even been around when I joined DIY) when I posted this question: [How do I get the most out of cracked lumber?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/126791/how-do-i-get-the-most-out-of-cracked-lumber)

But it looks like it is a better fit for Woodworking than DIY. Is a question here the right way to request a migration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can flag the question using the "other" option for a moderator to migrate.

However, you need to consider the following:

1. Is your question actually off topic here. There is an overlap between the sites and some questions will fit either. In this case you're probably right about where the best place is, but usually we don't migrate good on topic questions.
2. If the question has no answers or only one zero scoring answer then you can delete it yourself and repost on Woodworking. The drawback here is that deleted questions count when the system looks at limiting your ability to post, so delete with care.

Very much related - [Should we migrate on-topic questions that are better suited to Woodworking?](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1071/should-we-migrate-on-topic-questions-that-are-better-suited-to-woodworking?rq=1)